# How to upload a folder/file on onedrive using the onedrive sdk for windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, onedrive

I'm trying to use the onedrive sdk to upload content with [this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md) link.

Edit:

- I have permission to write files into the onedrive.
- I'm able to login and view the folders of the onedrive.
- Also the app is associated with the store.

Code:

```
using (contentStream)
{
    var uploadedItem = await oneDriveClient
                                 .Drive
                                 .Root
                                 .ItemWithPath("path/to/file.txt")
                                 .Content
                                 .Request()
                                 .PutAsync<Item>(contentStream);
}
```

what exactly is path/to/file.txt and what is contentStream? Can someone give me a clear example as I'm getting a 'Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.OneDriveException'.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but seems that *path/to/file.txt* stands for destination of new file on OneDrive and contentStream is a stream of data which will be uploaded to the file. What kind of exception you get? Have you logged in with upload capability, have you checked if suitable folders exist? The OneDrive API has quite good documentation, you can also take a look at source code.

Comment: @Romasz I have edited the question. I just have to figure out how can one get the path/to/file.txt is it from the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the sections of the documentation you might want to take a look at is the authentication process as this will get your started in using the [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/auth.md) in your UWP application.

To break down what's going on in the example code they've posted for you, the contentStream is the file you're wanting to uploading in the form of a stream. If you're using a StorageFile object to upload to OneDrive, you'll need to call the OpenStreamForReadAsync method on the storage file to get the contentStream which is present in the sample.

The "path/to/file.txt" section is where you'd like to store the file within the OneDrive root folder. So if you add a folder structure here, you'll put it in there, for example, if you're uploading **image.jpg**, you might have the following **/AppId/Images/image.jpg**.

Comment: Could you tell exactly what does /AppId/ here mean and how do I access it. Cause using CurrentApp.AppId gives me a system exception. And also how does one upload a folder?

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, that is just the path you want to place the file in OneDrive. So AppId would be the name of a folder on the root of your OneDrive file structure called AppId.

Comment: And to upload a folder of files, you'd probably have to loop through the files uploading each one at a time.

Comment: Oh I got the path as '/drive/root/myfolder/myfile.txt' using this I tried to upload there was no error but the file didn't get uploaded. And I was wondering how to create a folder first?

Comment: I figured it out. My local onedrive folder was not getting refreshed but the content got uploaded. Thanks for your help.